# Accss ManyToMany through model attribute for spcific row in drf serilizaer

Tags: python-3.x, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

I'm using Django 4.2 with Django-rest-framework and I need some help with returning a serialized object.

I have 2 models that have many to many relationship using a through model to hold a bit more logic

I want to return a serialized object that includes an extra attribute from the through model.
How can I do that?

My models:

```py
class Chart(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class MonitoredFlow(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)    
    charts = models.ManyToManyField(Chart,
                                    through="ChartFlows",
                                    related_name="monitored_flows",
                                    through_fields=("monitored_flow", "chart")
                                    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class ChartFlow(models.Model):
    chart = models.ForeignKey(Chart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    monitored_flow = models.ForeignKey(MonitoredFlow, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_monitored_flow_visible_on_chart = models.BooleanField(default=True)


        class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["chart", "monitored_flow"],
                name="unique_monitored_flow_and_chart_combination"
            ),
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.chart.name}: {self.monitored_flow.name}"
```

When retrieving a Chart object, I would like to know for the monitored flow if he is visible (or not) on the specific chart.
I would like to get from my view or serializer an object that looks something like this:

```js
{
    "id": 1,
    "name: "some chart name",
    "monitored_flows": [
        "id": 1,
        "name": "some flow name",
        "is_visible": true
    ]

}
```

My challenge is how to add the **is_visible** attribute from the through model.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I've found, not sure about query efficiency though.
I'm passing down the **chart_id** in the serialzier context using **to_representation** on the chart serializer.

My serializers:

```py
class MonitoredFlowSerializerForChart(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_visible = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MonitoredFlow
        fields = ['id', 'is_visible', 'name']        

    def get_is_visible(self, obj):
        result = obj.chartflow_set.get(chart_id=self.context.get("chart_id"))
        return result.is_monitored_flow_visible_on_chart

class ChartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    monitored_flows = MonitoredFlowSerializerForChart(many=True, required=False,
                                                      max_length=MAX_AMOUNT_OF_MONITORED_FLOWS_PER_CHART)

    class Meta:
        model = Chart
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'name', 'monitored_flows']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        self._context["chart_id"] = instance.id
        return super().to_representation(instance)
```